# textarea Allow line to be passed as content (jquery)

Tags: jquery, append, textarea, line, chat

why When I press enter, it sends the blank even though I prevented it from doing so in the condition

```js
$(".chat-end textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    let text = $(this).val();

    if (e.which === 13) {
        if (text !== "") {
            // here my problem Allow line to passed

            $(".chat-body").append("<p>" + text + "</p>");
            $(".chat textarea").val("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you put here working code as I check in this code does not have any problem.

Comment: Use either `if($.trim(text) !== "")` or `if(text != "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.chat-end textarea').keypress(function(e){

  let text = $(this).val();

 if(e.which === 13   ){

 if($("textarea").val().trim().length > 1)
  {
  $('.chat-body').append("<p>"+ text +"</p>");
  $('.chat textarea').val("");
  }

  }
  });
```